# How can I disable the calendar control if the user enters data manually?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS using input as date. But the datetime picker is not supported by Chrome, So I have added a jQuery date time picker. I have added the logic of finding the input control and replace that control with date time picker. In which I am facing an issue is if I have enter a date manually that calendar control is still shown. I would like to set the visibility of that calendar control if the user manually enter any values. Please find the attached screen shot.

The given below is the code I have used for this purpose.

```
 <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../../../../Core/Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../../Core/Includes/jquery-1.9.1.js">         
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../../Core/Includes/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $("#rpvReport__ctl0__ctl7__ctl0" ).datepicker();
        $("#rpvReport__ctl0__ctl5__ctl0" ).datepicker();
        $("#rpvReport__ctl0__ctl9__ctl0" ).datepicker();
        $("#rpvReport__ctl0__ctl11__ctl0" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script>
```

Any help is appreciated!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the keyup event (you can use keydown or keypress too).  Then you can evaluate the current value of the field.  If it is empty then show the datepicker control.  If not then hide the datepicker control.  See the following example.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").keyup(function(event) {
                                    if(event.target.value == ""){
                                        $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $("#datepicker").datepicker("hide");
                                    }
                               });
    });
    </script>
```